# Access GET request in another method django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form elements in my html.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="From" value="{{ request.GET.start_date }}">
            <input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="To" value="{{ request.GET.end_date }}">
</form>
```

I want to access to the `start_date` and `end_date` inside one of my view.py methods, but Im getting None all the time. 
So far I have tried:

```
temp = request.GET.get('start_date', None)
temp = request.GET['start_date']
```

What might be the problem? How can I access `start_date` and `end_date`?

EDIT: Im tring to access it in this method:

```
def download_pdf(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'invoice.pdf'

    books = books.objects.all()
    date = request.GET.get('start_date', None)
    books.filter(order__date = temp)

    c = canvas.Canvas(response)
    c.drawText(date)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    return response
```

Comment: Why do you say "in another method"? Is that the same view that is rendering the form in the first place? If not what is the relationship between them?

Comment: I submit the `start_date` before. I use it to filter books by dates. And then later, when I want to make pdf with the same filtered values, I call download_pdf

Comment: This makes no sense. How are you sending those request values to download_pdf? You need to show your whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `start_date` and `end_date` once you submit that form. Like POST method GET form also expect you to submit from the frontend.

```
<form action="." method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="From" value="{{ request.GET.start_date }}">
  <input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="To" value="{{ request.GET.end_date }}">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Or forget the form method just append the parameter in the url is enough. Like this...

```
http://localhost:8000/?start_date=test_start_date&end_date=test_end_date
```

Edit:

You have to check the GET dictionary before accessing. Because start_date will be not be present in the every GET request. Once the user submitted the GET request then we can access the GET parameter....

```
start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
if start_date:
    print(start_date)
```

Edit 2:

```
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
    if start_date:
        print(start_date)
    return render(request, 'base.html')


# base.html
<form action="." method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="From" value="testing">
  <input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="To" value="testing">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that. This gives me empty string OR gives me an error `Exception Value: 
"'start_date'"`

Comment: Yeah I also updated my answer... Actually you have to make sure start_date and end_date present in the GET request and then do your business logic else just pass something default to frontend,...

Comment: Still None :/ 
I make the submit in other method already. Then trying to access it. Any chance to put them together or access request later? Or make the date objects like global ?

Comment: See my Edit 2. This is working... Why you have the `value={{ request.GET.start_date }}` in my point of view it doesn't make any sense. Can you explain why you have that ?

Comment: That is just to show what the input was after writing it by the user

Comment: `return render(request, 'base.html')` gives `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">` but not the date...How can I get the start_date?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159371/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-averagejoe9000).